# Why can't the devices in my WLAN access Facebook servers but my smartphone can?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, facebook

This is the most bizarre thing I've ever seen in over a decade of networking.

I was using my computer normally this afternoon and then all of Facebook services stopped working (Whatsapp web, Facebook, Instagram etc) on my laptop.

But my smartphone, which was connected on nothing but my WiFi (it was on airplane mode), still could (and still can) access all of them.

And no, this isn't a DNS problem.

My computer is getting the same IP for Facebook (31.13.74.35) in both my ISP DNS and Google DNS (8.8.8.8).

But pinging for it is fruitless:

[image]

This time I left it trying for only 5 seconds, but if I leave it for minutes if gives no error either, no message, nothing.

It also fails trying to ping to [all of these IP ranges](https://gist.github.com/Whitexp/9591384) with nmap. None of them is up according to nmap when connected to my WiFI.

But, as my smartphone could access Facebook services normally, I thought something had to be wrong with my laptop.

I checked all network settings, after finding nothing wrong I tried booting a live Linux which I knew to be working, but nothing helped.

Then, out of curiosity, I installed a terminal emulator on my Android and tried pinging to those same IPs (all of that still only in the WiFI) and found out it also can't ping to them either:

[image]

In other words: The issue isn't the device, but that my local network can't connect to any of those IPs for whatever reason.

But then, how is my smartphone able to access Instagram and Facebook in my Chrome browser when connected to nothing but my WiFi???

It's clearly using the same DNS and getting the same IP as it's obvious from the ping in the terminal.

And no, it was not using mobile data. But talking about mobile data, if I connect to my 4G network and route it for my laptop, I can access that IP (31.13.74.35) normally, as well as dozens of IPs from those ranges I linked earlier.

So it seems that something is wrong with my network ISP in particular with the Facebook servers.

Also, several sites have been saying there's "unusual traffic" from my IP.

Maybe I've been used for an attack and my IP was blacklisted?

But even if it was, why and how can my smartphone access all of those sites, using my WiFi, with no mobile network enabled?

If itself can't ping to those IPs in the terminal when I try?

I can't explain anything that's going on here.

Comment: Ping is bad for testing. For using services Ping is not required so many server providers block ICMP ping requests/responses. So actually Ping is testing just if Ping works, not if something else works or if the server is reachable.

Comment: @Robert well, but I can ping normally to all of those using my 4G network. Plus, in my laptop at least, I can't reach those services by any other means either. None of the sites load. And if I load them using my routed 4G and then switch to my WiFi everything stops working too.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually half-solved the problem.

I still don't understand why, but it seems now that I can only access those servers via their IPv6 addresses.

My Linux Mint on my laptop was configured to ignore IPv6 configuration, and the Linux Live I had also ignored it.

Meanwhile, my smartphone used IPv6.

I only found that because I tested another Linux Live and it worked in the browser while pinging still didn't work, so I used `wget facebook.com` to see the output, and I saw several `301 Moved Permanently` errors when sending HTTP requests for the IPv4 addresses and that it eventually got it from an IPv6 address.

Re-enabling the IPv6 made everything get back to work.

So now the real question is: Why this sudden change?

I've been using this configuration for years.

And why aren't the IPv4 addresses reachable through my ISP's network but are reachable through my 4G network?

In my 4G network there is no such issue in the wget output, it gets it directly from the first IPv4 address it tries.

Considering that sites are now saying my IP presented unusual traffic, maybe computers in my ISP were used for an attack and they did some change in order to curb them?